# Can I send BEP-20 to web3 ethereumjs-wallet.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, web3js, bsc, bep20

I mainly use ethereumjs-wallet(https://www.npmjs.com/package/ethereumjs-wallet) based on web3 in nodejs to transmit ERC20.
This time, I suddenly became curious. If I send BEP-20, will ethereumjs-wallet recognize it properly?

I would like to check my balance and whether transfers are possible.
The environment I mainly use is nodejs.